# Calculating the size of memory needed to train ConvNet (using Caffe)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

Can anyone give a formula/guide to calculate the size of memory required when we want to train a Convolution Neural Network on a particular (image) data?
What settings to consider?

I implemented a simple ConvNet using Caffe with this specification: ImageData->Convolution->InnerProduct->SoftmaxWithLoss. I got these lines:

```
I0817 21:32:48.073011 11306 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer Layer1
I0817 21:32:48.073108 11306 net.cpp:91] Creating Layer Layer1
I0817 21:32:48.073148 11306 net.cpp:399] Layer1 -> data
I0817 21:32:48.073199 11306 net.cpp:399] Layer1 -> label
I0817 21:32:48.073256 11306 image_data_layer.cpp:38] Opening file ./data/ultrax/trainx/list.txt
I0817 21:32:48.073309 11306 image_data_layer.cpp:56] A total of 1 images.
I0817 21:32:48.084810 11306 image_data_layer.cpp:83] output data size: 32,3,224,224
I0817 21:32:48.151801 11306 net.cpp:141] Setting up Layer1
I0817 21:32:48.151892 11306 net.cpp:148] Top shape: 32 3 224 224 (4816896)
I0817 21:32:48.151921 11306 net.cpp:148] Top shape: 32 (32)
I0817 21:32:48.151942 11306 net.cpp:156] Memory required for data: 19267712
I0817 21:32:48.151968 11306 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer Layer2
I0817 21:32:48.152020 11306 net.cpp:91] Creating Layer Layer2
I0817 21:32:48.152068 11306 net.cpp:425] Layer2 <- data
I0817 21:32:48.152104 11306 net.cpp:399] Layer2 -> conv1
I0817 21:32:48.152740 11306 net.cpp:141] Setting up Layer2
I0817 21:32:48.152771 11306 net.cpp:148] Top shape: 32 64 216 216 (95551488)
I0817 21:32:48.152796 11306 net.cpp:156] Memory required for data: 401473664
I0817 21:32:48.152830 11306 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer Layer3
I0817 21:32:48.152863 11306 net.cpp:91] Creating Layer Layer3
I0817 21:32:48.152885 11306 net.cpp:425] Layer3 <- conv1
I0817 21:32:48.152910 11306 net.cpp:399] Layer3 -> fc
I0817 21:33:05.273979 11306 net.cpp:141] Setting up Layer3
I0817 21:33:05.274063 11306 net.cpp:148] Top shape: 32 64 (2048)
I0817 21:33:05.274085 11306 net.cpp:156] Memory required for data: 401481856
I0817 21:33:05.274127 11306 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer loss
I0817 21:33:05.512080 11306 net.cpp:91] Creating Layer loss
I0817 21:33:05.512157 11306 net.cpp:425] loss <- fc
I0817 21:33:05.512195 11306 net.cpp:425] loss <- label
I0817 21:33:05.512229 11306 net.cpp:399] loss -> loss
I0817 21:33:05.512287 11306 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer loss
I0817 21:33:05.512351 11306 net.cpp:141] Setting up loss
I0817 21:33:05.512387 11306 net.cpp:148] Top shape: (1)
I0817 21:33:05.512413 11306 net.cpp:151]     with loss weight 1
I0817 21:33:05.710017 11306 net.cpp:156] Memory required for data: 401481860
I0817 21:33:05.710049 11306 net.cpp:217] loss needs backward computation.
I0817 21:33:05.710068 11306 net.cpp:217] Layer3 needs backward computation.
I0817 21:33:05.710084 11306 net.cpp:217] Layer2 needs backward computation.
I0817 21:33:05.733338 11306 net.cpp:219] Layer1 does not need backward computation.
I0817 21:33:05.733397 11306 net.cpp:261] This network produces output loss
I0817 21:33:05.733440 11306 net.cpp:274] Network initialization done.
I0817 21:33:06.133980 11306 solver.cpp:60] Solver scaffolding done.
I0817 21:33:06.459244 11306 caffe.cpp:219] Starting Optimization
I0817 21:33:06.483875 11306 solver.cpp:279] Solving UltraNerveSegmentation
I0817 21:33:06.483947 11306 solver.cpp:280] Learning Rate Policy: step
I0817 21:33:20.800559 11306 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 0, Testing net (#0)
I0817 21:42:49.588776 11306 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: loss = 87.3365 (* 1 = 87.3365 loss)
I0817 21:48:44.556177 11306 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 0, loss = 87.3365
I0817 21:48:46.329630 11306 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 87.3365 (* 1 = 87.3365 loss)
I0817 21:48:46.760141 11306 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 0, lr = 0.0001
Killed
```

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385351/how-to-setup-caffe-imagenet-solver-prototxt-file-for-fewer-jpgs-program-exited), one said it might be the memory issue. Hence, IMHO, it will be good if we can estimate the required memory before we train the net so that we won't end up with killed process after waiting for so long.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using 32 bit floats, you can estimate that each element of each convolutional layer is one float.

So for each layer, compute how many neurons are in that layer based on the filter size, add up all the layers and multiply by 32 to get how many bits, and by 4 to get how many bytes you are using. You have to do this for the conv, pooling, and normalizing layers as well, in addition to the output layer. Also, whatever your batch size is, you have to multiply by that since your computer may load the entire batch into memory (unless there's a way to stream batches).